# How to store array values in Jmeter variables?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a CSV file containing data which I read using a Bean Shell script and populate an ArrayList based upon it.Below is the code for it.

```
//Populate Beanshell script
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

ArrayList strList = new ArrayList();    

try {
File file = new File("path/to/csv");

if (!file.exists()) {
    throw new Exception ("ERROR: file not found");
}

BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = null;

while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null) {
    strList.add(line);
}

bufRdr.close();   
}
catch (Exception ex) {
IsSuccess = false; 
log.error(ex.getMessage());
System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
catch (Throwable thex) {
System.err.println(thex.getMessage());
}
```

Now I want to utilize this data in a random manner so I am trying to use something like this

```
//Consumer bean shell script
//Not able to access strList since vars.put cannot store an object
Random rnd = new java.util.Random(); 
vars.put("TheValue",strList.get(rnd.nextInt(strList.size())));
```

But I am unable to do this because in vars.put I cannot store an array or a list,I can only store only primitive types.So there is no way in which I can access the populate function's ArrayList from an another BeanShell script.

How do I achieve randomization in this scenario since calling populate function each and every time is not good from a performance point of view.

Comment: And of what type is `vars` ?

Comment: vars is BeanShell scripting,think of it like Map.put

Comment: Can you show how you create `vars` ?

Comment: There is not create vars,this is specific to Jmeter,where I can store a variable like vars.put("key",value).And then I can access it like "${key}" in any Jmeter script.The issue is where I want to put a object type such as ArrayList which cannot be done,and anyone can suggest alternatives to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [bsh.shared](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/specialvarsvalues.html) namespace, this way you will be able to store any Java object and access it even from different Thread Groups if needed.

JMeter-specific example is in the official documentation, in [Sharing Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_variables) chapter

At the end of 1st script:

```
bsh.shared.strList = strList;
```

At the beginning of the 2nd script:

```
List strList = bsh.shared.strList;


Random rnd = new java.util.Random(); 
vars.put("TheValue",strList.get(rnd.nextInt(strList.size())));
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more details on Beanshell scripting for JMeter.

Comment: This seems to be better.But now there is another issue where the values do not get replaced sometimes.It just comes like "Thevalue" instead of the actual content.Maybe is it because I am running tests multithreaded.I know this is a different question,but I got stuck with it though.Is thread safety an issue here?

Comment: You can work it around as `vars.put("TheValue" + ctx.getThreadNum(), strList.get(rnd.nextInt(strList.size())));` so for 1st thread it'll be `TheValue1`, for the 2nd thread `TheValue2`, etc. There is a `__threadNum()` function which can be used in non-Beanshell test elements for getting current thread number: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum

Comment: It is now possible to use getObject() and putObject() on vars.

Answer (score 7):

`vars.put` only supports String values. There is [vars.putObject](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html):

> Scripts can also access JMeter variables using the get() and put()
>   methods of the "vars" variable, for example: vars.get("HOST");
>   vars.put("MSG","Successful"); . The get() and put() methods only
>   support variables with String values, but there are also getObject()
>   and putObject() methods which can be used for arbitrary objects.
>   JMeter variables are local to a thread, but can be used by all test
>   elements (not just Beanshell).

Comment: have you tryed this? Actually, it throws the error: 

    javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:    No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList$SubList)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help someone.

For sharing variables globally, i.e. among threads in all thread groups, use `props`.

For e.g,

- In setup thread group, do this 
  `props.put("mylist", new ArrayList());`
- Now, in post processor for every thread in the thread group, add values to the list.
  `props.get("mylist").add(<some value>);`
- In tear down thread group, fetch the entire list again.

  `log.info(props.get("mylist").toString());`

In thread group, list is updated by multiple threads then prefer to use Vector instead of ArrayList.

Ref : [scope-of-variables-sharing-among-threads-and-thread-groups](http://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-understanding-the-scope-of-variables-sharing-among-threads-and-thread-groups/)