# Unable to call object from a List located in external BeanShell script [Jmeter]

Tags: list, jmeter, beanshell

My end goal here is to get a string from a list that is created dynamically from a JSON response. I am having troubles calling a value from the list that is created in an external BeanShell script. The external script reads the JSON response and creates the list from the filtered response.

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Filter;

try{

    String json = new String(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

    List allPositiveAffects = JsonPath.read(json, "$.affectTags[?(@.value > 0.0)].key", new Filter[]{});
    vars.putObject("allPositiveAffects",allPositiveAffects);
    log.info("allPositiveAffects: " + allPositiveAffects);

    int positiveAffectCount = allPositiveAffects.size();
    vars.put("positiveAffectCount",Integer.toString(positiveAffectCount));

} catch (Throwable ex){
    log.error("Error:\n", ex);
}
```

`allPositiveAffects` returns the expected values, so now I want to get one of those values into a subsequent JSON POST.

My Jmeter test setup:

```
- Thread Group
  + JSON GET request
    - BeanShell PostProcessor
  + JSON POST request
```

Attempting to get a value from `allPositiveAffects` has proven to be not as easy as calling `allPositiveAffects.get(n)` like I can within my BeanShell script.

I haven't figured out an easy way to get the contents of the Lists. Am I missing something? I have tried several different things in my `JSON POST request`. The latest being:

```
//json POST data
{
"entries":[
"id": -1,
"key": "${__BeanShell(${allPositiveAffects}.get(1))}"]
}
```

Which returns the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Any help on a solution or workaround for this would be greatly appreciated. It would be a lot easier for me to be able to call a List instead of creating various variables.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could just add `.toString()` to your expression like:

```
`${__BeanShell(${allPositiveAffects}.get(1).toString())}`
```

By the way, Beanshell has some performance overhead so I would rather suggest going for [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) which is available via [Extras with Libs Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasWithLibsSet/) of JMeter Plugins package, it should be more convenient and less resource consuming.

See [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to "Parsing JSON") for installation instructions and some JSON Path language reference examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately `${__BeanShell(${allPositiveAffects}.get(1).toString())}` still gives me the `ClassCastException` error. 

I was using the JSON Path Extractor that you mentioned, but I do have some pretty complex filters for some calls that require BeanShell. I may switch the easier filters to the Extractor plugin for performance.

When attempting to get a value created from the array created from the Extractor, I get and eval error. `Caused by: In file: inline evaluation of: ["affect1"...] Encountered "[" at line 1, column 1.`

Comment: I have been wasting too much time on this, but I guess I am confused as to why when I call `allPositiveAffects.get(n)` in the external BeanShell script, it returns the correct value, but does not do the same in the HTTP Request with the BeanShell function. 
A final desperate attempt was to iterate through `allPositiveAffects` and add it to a new ArrayList: 
`List positiveAffectsArray = new ArrayList();
    for (String affect : allPositiveAffects){
        positiveAffectsArray.add(affect);   
    }` That returns `ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by using one of your other [suggestions regarding shared variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381643/how-to-store-array-values-in-jmeter-variables). I defined `bsh.shared.allPositiveAffects = allPositiveAffects ` and then did an inline BeanShell `${__BeanShell(List allPositiveAffects = bsh.shared.allPositiveAffects; allPositiveAffects.get(${__Random(0,${positiveAffectCount})});)}`